# Поменять фон сайта на joomla 3.х

Tags: joomla, css, less

Подскажите, можно ли через админку поменять фон сайта или только через правку css и less?
 Тема называется freqyency http://taras25.tmweb.ru/

Answer (score 1):

Через админку разве что в настройках шаблонах. Если это хорошый шаблон, типа на фреймворках Gantry, WARP или T3 - тогда точно да.